# Typescript objects or classes: not possible to have additional properties when class implements interface?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, extension-methods

I was wondering why its not possible to implement additional properties or functions inside a typescript class when this class implements an interface... it says: ...`"Object literal may only specify known properties and "FirstName" does not exist in type persInterface"`..
I think in java its also possible to implement other props or functions, the implementas interface is just a mandatory subset of the class and not a restriction.. is that behaviour normal in Typescript?

```
interface persInterface {
         lastName: String,
         sayHello: () => number
     }

 var person: persInterface = { 
    FirstName:"Tom", 
    lastName:"Hanks", 
    sayHello: ()=>{ return 10} ,
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You talk about classes implementing interfaces, but then your example code doesn't do that, it just has an object literal. With that object literal, you've defined that it will be *exactly* a persInterface, which is why you get an error when trying to add a property that's not part of persInterface.

If you do actually try to have a class which implements an interface then you can do what you want, without any type errors ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgA7QM4ElzXk5AbwFgAoZZAGzgzADk4BbCALmQGUwpQBzAGjIUMcAJ4AJCJUoB7NgAoAlMgC8APmQgArowBG0MgF8yZBNQwZkABUzSQyYI1SUIzcBfRRsuWIhQlyFMgwwJ70TKzItNwgPADcgoFmYcxsUbzxARQItlGaCGDSUHLBoQwpkVy8fFQ0yRFpMUr%20gS3IYAAWwBgAdCW0ZSjKQSH94RmtgR1d3UkDKjWjzOOBRqQJQqISUtKKbFq60ETrrVAQYJpQdgCMAAzLFKsGQA)):

```
interface persInterface {
  lastName: string,
  sayHello: () => number
}

class Person implements persInterface {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  sayHello(): number {
    return 10;
  }
}


const person = new Person('tom', 'hanks');
```

If you're working with literals, then you'd want to create an interface that extends from the base interface and specify what the extra properties are:

```
interface persInterface {
  lastName: string;
  sayHello: () => number;
}

interface persPlusPlus extends persInterface {
  firstName: string;
}

const person: persPlusPlus = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Hanks",
  sayHello: () => { return 10; },
};
```

Comment: yeah you're right sorry I meant objects and I modified my question, so this defines exactly the objects that I want, but its not possible to extend my objects above my interface, right?

Comment: You can create an interface that extends from another interface, and then say that your object literal is of that extended type. I've added in an example of that.

Comment: I think you meant to use firstName in your persPlusPlus interface, right?

Comment: @pobzeb yep, thanks for the correction!